# CSS Circle Border?

Tags: css, border, geometry

I am wondering how to have a border that is circles or dots(not squared dots, `border: white dotted 2px;` <- I don't want this) in CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I would recommend using [CSS3 border-image](http://border-image.com/) with the understanding that IE10 and below will need a [polyfill](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/).

```
.bordered-box {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 27px;
    -moz-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 27 repeat;
    -webkit-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 27 repeat;
    -o-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 27 repeat;
    border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 27 fill repeat;
}
```

**Original Accepted Answer:**

The only way to guarantee that it shows up as circles across all browsers is to use an image.

There is a tutorial here: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/how-to-create-border-images-using-css3.html

CSS:

```
.dots {
    border-width: 30px;
    -webkit-border-image:url(images/dots.png) 30 repeat stretch;
    -moz-border-image:url(images/dots.png) 30 repeat stretch;
    border-image:url(images/dots.png) 30 repeat stretch;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="dots"></div>
```

Image:

[image: CSS3 image border of dots]

If you need it to work for IE, you could also just create a wrapper div that has a background of dots and just give the inner div a padding of whatever height the dots are.

Answer (score 2):

It's not well supported across browsers, but you should have a look at the css3 attribute border-image:

```
-moz-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Firefox */    
-webkit-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Safari and Chrome */    
-o-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Opera */    
border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round;
```

Comment: Hmmm... tried that and it didn't show up in chromium(open source version of chrome) on my Linux machine...

Comment: as i said is not supported across browsers, and the code i gave you is for the major browsers...

Comment: Yes I know. The people i'm expecting to come to the site are ones that use up to date browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If CSS3 is an option, the `border-image` property is your best bet. Here is a tutorial on this very topic: http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/